# Nested if statement returns no such item

Tags: python, path, zip, unzip

my scipt is working as in searching for zip files, unzip and do the things i want. But problem arise when i have nested zip files inside the zip file, so i thought maybe i copy the working if statement, make a few adjustments but i still cant get it to work.

```
print('Searching for ZipFiles')
for file in os.listdir(working_directory):
    zfile = file
    if zfile.endswith('.zip'):
        # Create a ZipFile Object and load sample.zip in it
        with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as zipObj:
           # Get a list of all archived file names from the zip
           listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
           # Iterate over the file names
           for fileName in listOfFileNames:
              zipObj.extract(fileName, './temp')
              maincom() #until here, my script is working, below is the new IF statement
              if fileName.endswith('.zip'):
                for file in os.listdir('.'):
                  zfile = file
                  if zfile.endswith('.zip'):
                  # Create a ZipFile Object and load sample.zip in it
                    with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as zipObj:
                       # Get a list of all archived file names from the zip
                       listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
                       # Iterate over the file names
                       for fileName in listOfFileNames:
                          zipObj.extract(fileName, '')
                          maincom()
```

what i want to achieve is to simply unzip the nested zip files in the current directory they are found, run maincom(), if possible, maybe delete the nested zip file after unzip completion

Thanks guys

Comment: At first, I think you should learn to use recursion.

Comment: ok let me look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import glob
import zipfile

while len(glob.glob(working_directory+"*zip")) != 0:
    for filename in glob.glob(working_directory+"*zip"):
        with ZipFile(filename, 'r') as zipObj:
            for fileName in zipObj.namelist():
                zipObj.extract(fileName, './temp')
                maincom()
```

In principle, this will loop until there is no more zipfile in your working directory.

Which means: if zipfiles are present at iteration 1 and contain other zipfiles, those will be extracted. Which means: zipfiles will be present at iteration 2. And will be extracted. Etc Etc...

Answer (score 0):

If your zipfiles are not all that big, it is not necessary to unzip anything to disk, just keep things in memory, the recursive zipfiles would be chained using the bytes object returned by the `zipobj.read(filename)`.

```
import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

def recursiveunziper(zipfile):
    with ZipFile(zipfile, 'r') as zipobj:
        for filename in zipobj.namelist():
            if filename.endswith('.zip'):
                recursiveunziper(BytesIO(zipobj.read(filename)))
            if filename.contains('foobar')
                maincom(zipobj.read(filename)) # sending bytes of foobar files to maincom

for filename in os.listdir(working_directory):
    if filename.endswith('.zip'):
        recursiveunziper(filename)
```

I don't know if your `maincom()` would run only in the innermost zipfile or in all zip files along the way. In the example it runs in all files containing 'foobar' in all zip files along the way. Make your adjustments in order to make it work your way.

The `BytesIO` is used to transform the bytes object in a seekable bytes object, in the same way it would be if it were a file.